# URL Regex not validating as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex below for URL Validation

```
^([hH][tT]{2}[pP][sS]?:\/\/)?([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

the above regex is not validating if we remove .com from https://www.google.com

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use on this form:

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:\/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

See this example testing on [regex101.com and work fine](https://regex101.com/r/rAjp6W/1)! I put some others validations to url path ;-)

Comment: not working in example also.. com is not considering